# How to check CheckBoxPreference is checked or not?

Tags: android, checkboxpreference

I have a Setting Page where I have added `CheckBoxPreference` I need to check whether the checkbox is checked or not? My code is :

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Google Maps">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:summary="@string/markerSummary"
        android:title="@string/markerTitle"
        android:key="@string/markerKey" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

In settingActivity.java

```
Preference DragPref = findPreference(getString(R.string.markerKey));
        DragPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                boolean checked = Boolean.valueOf(newValue.toString());
                return false;
            }
        });
```

This code is always returning false; And after adding above code its not changing to false. Can you help me how to achieve this?

Comment: why not cast the preference to CheckBoxPreference and use `isChecked()`?

Comment: boolean checked =preference.getBoolean("markerKey", true);

Comment: @ShantoGeorge  I am getting an error `Cannot resolve method getBoolean`

Comment: try this... `boolean checked = (Boolean) newValue;`

Comment: @JakirHossain Everytime its returning false, Didn't worked

Comment: another way you can try ... `boolean checked = newValue.toString().equals("true") ?  true:false;`

Comment: @JakirHossain Can you please rewrite the complete function in answer because the problem is after writing this I am not able do make the key false and And its always returning false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this, hope it will solve your problem.

```
Preference DragPref = findPreference(getString(R.string.markerKey));
    DragPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new  Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            boolean checked = (Boolean) newValue;
            return true; 
           // Note: return true to update the state of the Preference with the new value. If you want to disallow the change return false
        }
    });
```